# Javascript: Opening new windows interval of 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, firefox

This is my html code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Something</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <a href="http://jquery.com/">Try Me!</a>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
$("a").click(function(event){

for(id=0;id<=10;){
id++;
     setTimeout(function(){window.open("http://www.mysite.com/characterID="+id,"", "win1", "width=100,height=100,resizable");}, 3000);
   }
event.preventDefault();
});

   </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When I click "Try Me!" it opens the windows I need after 3 seconds. But I want to open first window, wait 3 seconds then second window, wait 3 seconds then third window.

İs it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use setInterval instead of setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Notice how I multiply the timeout by the number of iteration you are in. Also notice the syntax difference for the for loop:

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    for(i = 0; i< 10; i++)
        setTimeout(function(){window.open("http://www.mysite.com/characterID="+id,"", "win1", "width=100,height=100,resizable");}, 3000 * i);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function(event){
  for(id=0;id<=10;id++){
    var local_id = id;
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.open("http://www.mysite.com/characterID="+local_id,"", "win"+local_id, "width=100,height=100,resizable");
      }, 3000*id);
   }
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Multiple the timeout by your id and open each window 3 seconds after the next.

Comment: It always open this window(http://www.mysite.com/characterID=10) why?
I need that row; http://www.mysite.com/characterID=0, http://www.mysite.com/characterID=1, http://www.mysite.com/characterID=2...

Comment: You might have to change the name of "win1" to "win"+id

Comment: I changed my code.  I think the issue was that id was a global variable which equaled 10 after the for loop. If you save a local variable, it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it again.  The local variable needs to be declared outside the setTimeout function.